# Has RetrofitAdapter been replaced?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am going through a tutorial on treehouse and the tutorial uses Retrofit to work with an Api.  I am using version 2.0.0-beta3, and the RetrofitAdapter() method failed to import.  Is Retrofit() the replacement for RetrofitAdapter()?

Comment: I believe it is the new replacement. Check out this post to see the changes between Retrofit 1 and 2: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it has. You have to use `Retrofit.Builder`, whose build() method will return a `Retrofit` object. With retrofit 2 you will have to explicitly provide a converter for your response. E.g.:

```
Retrofit retroift = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

and on `retrofit` you'll call

```
 retroift.create(YourInterface.class);
```

where `YourInterface` contains your rest methods